# test_train_split converts string type label to np.array. Is there any way to get back the original label name?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have an image dataset with a string type label name. When I split the data using test_train_split of sklearn library, it converts the label to np.array type. Is there a way to get back the original string type label name?

The below code splits a data to train and test:

```
imgs, y = load_images()
train_img,ytrain_img,test_img,ytest_img = train_test_split(imgs,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

If I print y, it gives me the label name but if I print the splitted label value it give an array:

```
for k in y:
    print(k)
    break
for k in ytrain_img:
    print(k)
    break
```

Output:

```
 001.Affenpinscher
 [[[ 97 180 165]
  [ 93 174 159]
  [ 91 169 152]
  ...
 [[ 88 171 156]
 [ 88 170 152]
 [ 84 162 145]
 ...
 [130 209 222]
 [142 220 233]
 [152 230 243]]

 [[ 99 181 163]
 [ 98 178 161]
 [ 92 167 151]
 ...
 [130 212 224]
 [137 216 229]
 [143 222 235]]
 ...
 [[ 85 147 158]
 [ 85 147 158]
 [111 173 184]
 ...
 [227 237 244]
 [236 248 250]
 [234 248 247]]

 [[ 94 154 166]
 [ 96 156 168]
 [133 194 204]
 ...
[226 238 244]
[237 249 253]
[237 252 254]]
...
[228 240 246]
[238 252 255]
[241 255 255]]]
```

Is there a way to convert back the array to the original label name?

Comment: You should provide your code and refer to it to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are inferring the output of `train_test_split` wrong.

`train_test_split` works in this way:

```
A_train, A_test, B_train, B_test, C_train, C_test ... 
                             = train_test_split(A, B, C ..., test_size=0.2)
```

You can give as many arrays to split. For each given array, it will provide the train and test split first, then do the same for next array, then third array and so on..

So in your case actually it is:

```
train_img, test_img, ytrain_img, ytest_img = train_test_split(imgs, y, 
                                                              test_size=0.2, 
                                                              random_state=1)
```

But you are then mixing up the names of the output and using them wrong.